# our daughter is scared to come home

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "our daughter is scared to come home" as "our daughter is scared, (and so she) comes home." Am I on the right track?

The problem for the question is that it could be read in two ways:  It could either mean "our daughter is scared, so she dares not come home" or mean "our daughter is scared, so she decides that only home is safe and must come back."  I am not sure.

> In Israel, bombs fall, **our daughter is scared to come home**, hatred festers

Source: [USAToday](https://www.usatoday.com/story/opinion/voices/2021/05/18/israel-gaza-rockets-violence-endless-hatreds/5132041001/)

Comment: No you've misunderstood the words. If someone is ***scared TO do something***, that means they're frightened of the ***consequences*** of doing it (so they ***won't*** do it, ***because*** they are afraid).

Comment: If fear is the ***reason*** for someone doing something, that must be expressed using a different preposition *The boy was scared **into** handing over his lunch money to the school bully*. As opposed to *The boy was scared **to** tell the teacher what had happened, because he knew that would make the bully very angry*.

Comment: No, it cannot be read more than one way. It only means that she is scared of doing something so she doesn't do it.

Comment: (In your example context, the parents live in Israel. They're saying that because their daughter - who *doesn't* live in Israel - is afraid of the bombs, she ***won't*** go "home" to visit them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means roughly the opposite to what you think:

> Our daughter is scared, so she *won't* come home.

The expression "I am scared to do it" means I won't do it, because I am afraid.

In the context you give, it is implied that the daughter is currently living away from home, perhaps in another country.

It might be worth comparing with "our daughter has been scared into coming home." This means that she was scared and so she came home.

Comment: It might be worth comparing with "our daughter has been scared *into* coming home."  That seems close to what OP mistook the original model to sometimes mean.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I thought of that possibility too (see the OP:  It could either mean "our daughter is scared, so she dares not come home"). But I wondered:"If this was the case, shouldn't it use "too...to" structure ("our daughter is TOO scared to come home")"?   Now I am wondering whether the phrase "our daughter is TOO scared to come home" is natural in English. Do you native speakers never use the structure of the phrase? (That is, do you only stick to using "our daughter is scared to come home"?)

Comment: You could add the adverb "too",  but it still works without it. The meaning is unambiguous and as I have described in my answer.